# Show database records in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I'm in the middle of making an webapplication with CodeIgniter, but I'm stuck on displaying database records to the user. Currently I have this:

** MODEL **

```
function showAllUsers()
 {
    $this -> db -> select('id, username, password');
    $this -> db -> from('app_users');

    $query = $this -> db -> get();
    if($query -> num_rows() > 0)
    {


        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {

        return false;
    }

 }
```

** CONTROLLER **

```
function index()
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
        $data = array();
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['loggedin'] = $session_data['username'];
        $type = $this->fillUserModule();

        $naarview = array_merge( $data, $type );

        //$data['title'] = ucfirst($page); //Capitalize first letter
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('navbar.php');
        $this->load->view('pages/home', $naarview);

        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
   }
   else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }
 }

 function fillUserModule()
 {
    //Run the query for getting all users
    $result = $this->user->showAllUsers();


    if ($result)
    {
        var_dump($result);
        return $result;
    }
   else
   {



     return false;
   }
 }
```

If I dump the result I get this, this is from the $result query:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#20 (3) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["username"]=> string(3) "bob" 
        ["password"]=> string(32) "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055" 
       } 
   [1]=> object(stdClass)#21 (3) {
       ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
       ["username"]=> string(4) "huub" 
       ["password"]=> string(32) "258bb2089ad9345897565e3e7f023f6e" 
       } 
}
```

But I cannot seem to access it in the View. I can access the 'loggedin' variable but that one is clearly identified, but the array of the actual users, coming from the model and controller, I cannot access it, probably because it is an array, which is an stdClass?

Do I need to convert these values to another array so I can access  it?

Comment: What is the name of your view?

Comment: user.php is the name of my model, home.php is the name of my view!

Comment: Within your model you need to pass **$query->result_array()** instead of **$query->result()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you see how we send data to view from controller in codignator

```
function fillUserModule()
 {
   //Run the query for getting all users
    $result = $this->user->showAllUsers();
    if ($result)
    {  
         $data['result']=$result;
        //load view here
         $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
      else
   {
     return false;
   }
 }
```

In your viwe page you use

```
foreach($result as $val){
//your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've used your approach and I edited a few couple of things to make it work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$query->result_array()` instead of `$query->result()`. Result will be array, not object :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the controller like this

```
 $this->load->view('pages/home', array('naarview' => $naarview));
```

And access it in home view page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
function fillUserModule()
{
    //Run the query for getting all users
    $result = $this->user->showAllUsers();

    if ($result)
    {
        var_dump($result);
        echo $result->username."<br />";
        return $result;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can use `"->"` to access the object data like this : `echo $result->username."<br />";`